# How to notify JBoss with Oracle trigger

Tags: sql, oracle, hibernate, jboss, triggers

I need to implement the following:

There is a table A which is supposed to be changed by DML operations coming from trigger on another table B.

I want to notify Jboss bean every time the trigger works. In best case I'd like to have an opportunity to see OLD and NEW data in the bean.

What is the best way to do it? Could you recommend any material to read?

Comment: Have you investigated [database change notification](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E14072_01/java.112/e10589/dbchgnf.htm)?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Alex's proposal to use [Database Change Notification](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E14072_01/java.112/e10589/dbchgnf.htm) is probably the best way to go.
Here's a few other options for actions to signal an event to a Java process from an Oracle PL/SQL package (which you can call from a trigger):

- Use [DBMS_PIPE](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/appdev.111/b28419/d_pipe.htm#CHDDFCFC) to asynchronously send a message to a Java client listening on the same pipe.
- Use [DBMS_ALERT](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/appdev.111/b28419/d_alert.htm#CHDDJCJG) to send a message to a Java client listening on the target alert. The message will not be received until the transaction commits.
- Use [UTL_HTTP](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/appdev.102/b14258/u_http.htm#CHDIAFFA) or [UTL_SMTP](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/appdev.102/b14258/u_smtp.htm#CHDHHBJD) or [UTL_TCP](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/appdev.111/b28419/u_tcp.htm#CEGDFJJE) to send a message to a Java process listening on the target HTTP, SMTP or TCP endpoint.
- Send an [Oracle/AQ JMS](http://download.oracle.com/docs/cd/B10500_01/appdev.920/a96587/qintro.htm) message to a Java client listening on the target queue/topic.
- Create a JMS client in Java and [load the java classes](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B10501_01/java.920/a96659.pdf) [and dependencies] into the Oracle database. Wrap the class in a PL/SQL procedure and call it to signal a Java client listening on the target queue/topic.

There's a lot more info on sending JMS messages from PL/SQL in the question [Calling/Using JMS from PL/SQL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5819420/calling-using-jms-from-pl-sql).

Comment: These solutions are complex to set up and maintain.  In all but JMS messages can get lost.    I'm surprised many people liked this answer!

Comment: Can I just call some java method in the trigger that will look up a bean and invoke its method?

Comment: Oleg; Sort of. Not to state the obvious, but the java method will need to be wrapped in PL/SQL. It's a bit of a rough road, I must tell you. The problem is that it requires a wide load of classes to be loaded to reproduce the remote client. But it does work.

Answer (score 0):

You could have the trigger insert a row in a signal table.

A JBoss process could then monitor the signal table, checking for new signals at regular intervals.

Comment: Yes, it's a simplest solution but in case of triggers on many tables i will have to have same number of the signal tables, or manage the column values via parameter table